# How to open a Existing xlsx file as a Pop up for SAVE/OPEN in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, openxml-sdk

I have a ASP.net application in which we are creating xlsx files using OPENXML, we are able to create xlsx file & save it into one of the folder in application.

*But Now we want to show that file as a SAVE/Open dialog pop up.* 
(As shown in IMAGE below)
So what need to change/add in code?

Instead of giving fixed path of drive folder on disk, Can we store it in Memorystream & directly display that file as pop up.

[image]

```
  string path = Context.Server.MapPath("~/ExcelData/Business_Summary_"+name+".xslx");
        ExportDataSet(ds, path);



     private void ExportDataSet(DataSet ds, string destination)
{
    using (var workbook = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(destination, DocumentFormat.OpenXml.SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook))
    {
        var workbookPart = workbook.AddWorkbookPart();

        workbook.WorkbookPart.Workbook = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Workbook();

        workbook.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Sheets = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheets();

        foreach (System.Data.DataTable table in ds.Tables)
        {

            var sheetPart = workbook.WorkbookPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
            var sheetData = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.SheetData();
            sheetPart.Worksheet = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Worksheet(sheetData);

            DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheets sheets = workbook.WorkbookPart.Workbook.GetFirstChild<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheets>();
            string relationshipId = workbook.WorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(sheetPart);

            uint sheetId = 1;
            if (sheets.Elements<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheet>().Count() > 0)
            {
                sheetId =
                    sheets.Elements<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheet>().Select(s => s.SheetId.Value).Max() + 1;
            }

            DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheet sheet = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheet() { Id = relationshipId, SheetId = sheetId, Name = table.TableName };
            sheets.Append(sheet);

            DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Row headerRow = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Row();

            List<String> columns = new List<string>();
            foreach (System.Data.DataColumn column in table.Columns)
            {
                columns.Add(column.ColumnName);

                DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Cell cell = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Cell();
                cell.DataType = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellValues.String;
                cell.CellValue = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellValue(column.ColumnName);
                headerRow.AppendChild(cell);
            }


            sheetData.AppendChild(headerRow);

            foreach (System.Data.DataRow dsrow in table.Rows)
            {
                DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Row newRow = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Row();
                foreach (String col in columns)
                {
                    DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Cell cell = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Cell();
                    cell.DataType = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellValues.String;
                    cell.CellValue = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellValue(dsrow[col].ToString()); //
                    newRow.AppendChild(cell);
                }

                sheetData.AppendChild(newRow);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Updated Code :

```
 HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearHeaders();
     HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();
     HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
     HttpContext.Current.Response.Buffer = true;
     HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=Export.xlsx");
     HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
    //  HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xls";
     HttpContext.Current.Response.Charset = "";

     MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();



 objSpreadsheet.Close();
         ms.WriteTo(HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream);
         ms.Close();
        // HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
         HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream.Close();
```

But still does not get xlsx  as a pop up

Comment: Are you exactly want to display excel sheet as a pop with save open Buttons...?

Comment: Yes, I have already tried few things but it still does not work for me.